# docker: split structure into usefull networks

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-network

I'm not quite sure about the correct usage of docker networks.

I'm running a (single hosted) reverse proxy and the containers for the application itself, but I would like to set up networks like `proxy`, `frontend` and `backend`. The last one for project1, assuming there could be multiple projects at the end.
But I'm even not sure, if this structure is the way it should be done. I think the backend should only be accessable for the frontend and the frontend should be accessable for the proxy.

So this is my current working structure with only one network (bridge) - which doesn't make sense:

1. Reverse proxy (network: reverse-proxy):

   - jwilder/nginx-proxy
   - jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
2. Database

   - mongo:3.6.2
3. Project 1

   - one/frontend
   - one/backend
   - two/frontend
   - two/backend

So my first docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/docker/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /opt/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/docker/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /opt/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: "nginx-proxy"

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:3.6.2
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

volumes:
  html:

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy
```

That means I had to create the *reverse-proxy* before. I'm not sure if this is correct so far.

The project applications - frontend containers and backend containers - are created by my CI using docker commands (not docker compose):

```
docker run
  --name project1-one-frontend
  --network reverse-proxy
  --detach
  -e VIRTUAL_HOST=project1.my-server.com
  -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=project1.my-server.com
  -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=mail@my-server.com
  project1-one-frontend:latest
```

How should I split this into useful networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; You can attach multiple networks to a given container, which let's you isolate traffic to a great degree.

> useful networks

Point of context, I'm inferring from the question that "useful" means there's some degree of isolation between services.

> I think the backend should only be accessable for the frontend and the frontend should be accessable for the proxy.

This is pretty simple with `docker-compose`. Just specify the networks you want at the top level, just like you've done for `reverse-proxy`:

```
networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Then something like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      ...

  frontend1:
    image: some/image
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
      - backend

  backend1:
    image: some/otherimage
    networks:
      - backend

  backend2:
    image: some/otherimage
    networks:
      - backend

  ...
```

Set up like this, only *frontend1* can reach *backend1* and *backend2*. **I know this isn't an option**, since you said you're running the application containers (frontends and backends) via `docker run`. But I think it's a good illustration of how to achieve roughly what you're after within Docker's networking.

So how can you do what's illustrated in `docker-compose.yml` above? I found this: https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks

To summarize, you can only attach one network using `docker run`, but you can use `docker network connect <container> <network>` to connect running containers to more networks after they're started.

The order in which you create networks, run `docker-compose up`, or run your various containers in your pipeline is up to you. You can create the networks inside the `docker-compose.yml` if you like, or use `docker network create` and import them into your `docker-compose` stack. It depend on how you're using this stack, and that will determine the order of operations here.

The guiding rule, probably obvious, is that the networks need to exist before you try to attach them to a container. The most straightforward pipeline might look like..

1. `docker-compose up` with all networks defined in the `docker-compose.yml`
2. for each app container:

   `docker run` the container

   `docker network attach` the right networks

Answer (score 1):

> ... would like to set up networks like proxy, frontend and backend. ... I think the backend should only be accessable for the frontend and the frontend should be accessable for the proxy.

Networks in docker don't talk to other docker networks, so I'm not sure if the above was in reference to networks or containers on those networks. What you can have is a container on multiple docker networks, and it can talk with services on either network.

The important part about designing a network layout with docker is that any two containers on the same network can communicate with each other and will find each other using DNS. Where people often mess this up is creating something like a proxy network for a reverse proxy, attaching multiple microservices to the proxy network and suddenly find that everything on that proxy network can find each other. So if you have multiple projects that need to be isolated from each other, they cannot exist on the same network.

In other words if app-a and app-b cannot talk to each other, but do need to talk to the shared proxy, then the shared proxy needs to be on multiple app specific networks, rather than each app being on the same shared proxy network.

This can get much more complicated depending on your architecture. E.g. one design that I've been tempted to use is to have each stack have it's own reverse proxy that is attached to the application private network and to a shared proxy network without publishing any ports. And then a global reverse proxy publishes the port and talks to each stack specific reverse proxy. The advantage there is that the global reverse proxy does not need to know all of the potential app networks in advance, while still allowing you to only expose a single port, and not have microservices connecting to each other through the shared proxy network.

Comment: That sounds very logical. I am not very experienced with reverse proxies. As I said, I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` as a reversed proxy - also to get the lets encrypt certificates managed. So I am not sure how to set up a second proxy as you explained. Could you please show an example? Maybe a docker-compose modification of mine? I don't understand how to setup a second proxy between my current proxy and the frontend of my project 1 for example.